# Why am I getting this counter-intuitive relevancy result to a MySQL full-text query?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm querying for `+2019* +sponsor* +BGHDA*`

and getting this result:

**2019 sponsor BGHDA   #7   Springfield, WA 2019 03 04**

relevancy: 34.139

**2019 sponsor BGHDA**

relevancy: 26.087

Given that my search terms account for a higher percentage of the 2nd result than of the 1st result, I'd expect its relevancy to be higher, but in fact it's lower.

If I remove the `+` and `*` from the query leaving `2019 sponsor BGHDA` I get similar results, which seems even weirder - the 2nd result is a perfect match!

If I add quotes (`"2019 sponsor BGHDA"`) this problem STILL exhibits itself...

Can someone explain to me in simple terms why this is?  And what tricks I might employ to turn this the other way around?

Thanks

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `FULLTEXT` is full of oddities.  Which Engine are you using?  They give different relevance factors.